# DDD, Anti Corruption layer, how-to?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, url-rewriting, legacy

At the moment, we have to build an application which is based on a legacy one.  Code for that old application should be thrown away and rewritten, but as it usually goes - instead of rewriting it, we need to base something new on it. Recently, we decided to go the DomainDrivenDesign path.  So -- anti corruption layer could be a solution for our problems. As far as I understand, this way it should be possible to gradually rewrite the old application.

But -- I can't find any good example. I would appreciate **ANY** information.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In my particular implementation, EmployeeAccessService is called by a Repository. It's really a facade into the Anti-corruption layer. It delegates to the EmployeeAccessAdapter. The adapter fetches an object from the legacy model (which it gets from EmployeeAccessFacade),then passes it to the EmployeeAccessTranslator to transform the object from the legacy model to the domain object in my application's model.

**EmployeeAccessService**

```java
public Employee findEmployee(String empID){
    return adapter.findEmployee(empID);
}
```

**EmployeeAccessAdapter**

```java
public Employee findEmployee(String empID){
    EmployeeAccessContainer container = facade.findEmployeeAccess(empID);
    return translator.translate(container);
}
```

**EmployeeAccessTranslator**

```java
public Employee translate(EmployeeAccessContainer container){
    Employee emp = null;
    if (container != null) {
        employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmpID(idPrefix + container.getEmployeeDTO().getEmpID());
        ...(more complex mappings)
```

Answer (score 40):

From **the** [DDD book (Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) by Eric Evans:

> The public interface of the
>   ANTICORRUPTION LAYER usually appears
>   as a set of SERVICES, although
>   occasionally it can take the form of
>   an ENTITY.

and a bit later

> One way of organizing the design of
>   the ANTICORRUPTION LAYER is as a
>   combination of FACADES, ADAPTERS (both
>   from Gamma et al. 1995), and
>   translators, along with the
>   communication and transport mechanisms
>   usually needed to talk between
>   systems.

So, you might find examples by looking at the suggested [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) and [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

I'll try to paraphrase what Eric Evans said, your anti-corruption layer will appear as services to the outside of your layer. So outside of the anti-corruption layer the other layers will not know they are "speaking" with a anti-corruption layer. Inside of the layer you would use adapters and facades to wrap your legacy information sources.

More information about the anti-corruption layer:

- [Anatomy of an Anti-Corruption Layer, Part 1](http://moffdub.wordpress.com/2008/09/21/anatomy-of-an-anti-corruption-layer-part-1/)
- [Building the often needed anti-corruption layer](http://lostechies.com/joeybeninghove/2007/09/10/building-the-often-needed-anti-corruption-layer/)

Comment: Thanks. I will check those out right now. But i got a feeling already that it won't be enough. Aren't there any code examples? :)

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_wrapper402122006091959AM/csharp_wrapper4.aspx this one is great to understand Adapter pattern :)

Comment: Links 
Building the often needed anti-corruption layer(http://joeydotnet.com/blog/archive/2007/09/10/building-the-often-needed-anti-corruption-layer.aspx) and 
DDD - Anti corruption layer(http://www.goeleven.com/blog/entryDetail.aspx?entry=168 ) are broken

Comment: This is super old I realize but to answer the OP you're not going to find code samples for an ACL. Patterns are too high level and there are too many variables for a cookie-cutter recipe. My advice is if the ACL is needed just for the life of the migration and no longer then don't get fancy. It doesn't have to be pretty. Just write tests and make sure it works. Data integrity is key here not performance or beautifully refactored code.

Comment: only one of those 3 links at the end are opened